# How to place a widget in specific position of a resizable page? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm working on a page where there are some fields like `textfield` and a `slider`. At the end of the page there must be a button for proceeding to next step which is wrapped in an `Align` to have a fixed position across pages.

On the other hand, the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` attribute is `true`; so, when someone taps on a `textfield` the page resizes to keep `textfield` visible. The problem is that in case of tapping the textfield, the button moves upward to the middle of page.

Now, what I want, is a way to place the button in a fixed position while the page remains resizable.

here is the `build`'s code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
        child: Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              const Background(),
              getTopbar(),
              getBody(),
              getProceedButton()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

here is an abstract version of `getBody`'s function:

```
return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: topbarHeigthSmall),
    child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - topbarHeigthSmall,
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, left: 30),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                    children: [
                        //children of page like textfields and ... 
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

and finally the code for `button`:

```
Widget getProceedButton() {
    return Align(
      alignment: const Alignment(0.0, 0.8),
      child: Container(...),
    );
}
```

Here is a screenshot before tapping a `textfield`:
link to image

[image]

Here is another screenshot afterwards:
[image: link to image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put your button widget inside of Positioned, like this:

```
Positioned(
          top:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: button(),);
```

Comment: Actually, I'd tried this before, and it didn't seem working. But, there is a little trick using which the solution works, and that is to give the top attribute a value like:  "MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8" rather than filling bottom attribute. If you fill the bottom attribute, the button moves upward on tapping textfields again. Anyway, Thanks for giving the clue!